# Clipboard API and inconsistent browser behaviors between OSes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clipboard

I am attempting to troubleshoot an issue where Windows users of our React application are unable to copy and paste content that non Windows users can.

We have content displaying in a react-modal window, with a button that, when clicked, highlights the region to be copied, and copies to the clipboard buffer for pasting.

We are running the following in an onCopy event triggered by a click event on the button:

```
const range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(this.getCiteTextNode()); // function to get the node
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);

const listener = document.addEventListener("copy", e => {
  const outerHTML = this.getCitationTextWithoutStyle(); //function strips styling attributes
  e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", outerHTML);
  e.preventDefault();
});

document.execCommand("copy");
document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
```

What I have observed is that while browsers on MacOS (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) will allow this copying/pasting operation to occur, in Windows, Edge, FF, and Chrome fail silently (nothing is in the clipboard buffer), even though programmatic access has been granted in those browsers. What's more is it appears ANY copying pasting request (menu, mouse or keyboard) fails silently; I can manually highlight a different region of the modal, select copy, and attempt to paste in another document and it simply does not copy - nothing makes it to the buffer.

This, however, *does* work in IE11 - with a prompt - but clipboard access behaves normally when the button click event is triggered.

Further experimentation revealed that this works on Windows browsers when I change `preventDefault` to `stopPropagation`. Once I do this, content makes it to the clipboard correctly.

Has anyone ever encountered this? How does preventing event bubbling get this "working" in Windows only browsers?

PS - aware of the draft status of execCommand.

Thanks

Comment: You're removing the event listener incorrectly. I doubt it's *the* problem, but it's certainly *a* problem, because your handler is never removed. `addEventListener` returns `undefined`, not the handler function, but you need to supply the handler function to `removeEventListener` for it to work. So `const listener = e => { /*...your handler code...*/ }; document.addEventListener("copy", listener); /*...*/ document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);`

Comment: You're right, thank you for this added context. But yeah, the behavior in Windows browsers is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

***Preamble***: *This answer tries to explain what the code in OP is doing, what they* may *have faced, and how they should handle it, however, it is a bit weakened by the fact that both Windows and macOs actually behave the same for me...*

---

If we take step by step your code, it is

- Select a Node in the DOM.
- Execute a `copy` command
  [internal browser logic]
    => Fire a `copy` event
- Handle the `copy` event
- Set the event's DataTransfer data.
  => Set `outerHTML` as `text/html` in the clipboard
- Prevent the default action of the `copy` event.

If not prevented, the "*default action*" should have been,

=> Grab the markup of the active Selection as `text/HTML` in the clipboard.
    => Grab the `toString()` of the Selection as `text/plain` in the clipboard.

Maybe you already see what your code is missing:

**You do not set the `text/plain` value of your copy event**.

Only a few applications will try to grab the `text/html` data from the clipboard, most will just search for the `text/plain` value.

So you need to set it as well.

Here is a little playground* where you can see that even in a web-page, only some places do allow to paste as `text/html`, while others will use the `text/plain` value.

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(copyme); // function to get the node
  const selection = getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  const listener = e => {
    // make it green in the clipboard
    const outerHTML = copyme.outerHTML.replace('red', 'green');
    // add some text to show we have the control
    const plaintext = selection.toString() + ' plaintext';

    const dT = e.clipboardData;
    dT.setData("text/html", outerHTML);
    // IIRC IE does only support `"text"` MIME type
    dT.setData("text", plaintext);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

```css
[contenteditable] {border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<button id="btn">copy</button>

<span id="copyme" style="color:red">Hello</span>
<br>

<!-- contenteditable elements will grab the text/html data -->
<div contenteditable>paste HTML here<br> </div>

<!-- <textarea> and <input> will only grab the text/plain -->
<textarea>paste plain here
</textarea>
```

<sub>* I fixed a few unrelated typos from your original code, like the incorrect event removal pointed in the comments to your question.</sub>

---

Also note that it wasn't `stopPropagation` that was doing any magic, but simply the fact that you didn't call `preventDefault`.
Doing so, the default behavior of copying both the markup of the Node returned by `this.getCiteTextNode()` as `text/html` and its textContent as `text/plain` was overriding your own setting.

Here is an example with a checkbox controlling whether the default behavior should be prevented or not. You can see that when it's not prevented, then the rich-text copied is still *red*, instead of the green we do set in the event handler, and the plain-text is still the node's textContent, instead of our edited text.

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(copyme); // function to get the node
  const selection = getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  const listener = e => {
    // make it green in the clipboard
    const outerHTML = copyme.outerHTML.replace('red', 'green');
    // add some text to show we have the control
    const plaintext = selection.toString() + ' plaintext';

    const dT = e.clipboardData;
    dT.setData("text/html", outerHTML);
    // IIRC IE does only support `"text"` MIME type
    dT.setData("text", plaintext);
   if(prev.checked) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

```css
[contenteditable] {border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<label>prevent default behavior<input type="checkbox" id="prev" checked></label><br>
<button id="btn">copy</button>

<span id="copyme" style="color:red">Hello</span>
<br>

<!-- contenteditable elements will grab the text/html data -->
<div contenteditable>paste HTML here<br> </div>

<!-- <textarea> and <input> will only grab the text/plain -->
<textarea>paste plain here
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I _want_ the content as HTML. The way the code is written currently the contents have formatting preserved so it pastes with formatting in rich text docs, and without when pasting into plain-text documents. It also doesn't quite explain why this works with `stopPropagation` either, or why `preventDefault` only works in MacOS browsers. Lastly, I can find no documentation that describes needing to invoke `setData` twice (once with an html format, then text) in the copy event order to paste HTML.

Comment: It is not stopPropagation that did any magic, but if you don't prevent the default behavior, then your own setData is overwritten by the default one, which does set both as explained in the answer. For docs... it's just DataTransfer.setData, you need to set the Mime types you want to be set. And I still don't get what you want... You only want the markup as plain text? Or the *rich-text*?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with a checkbox controlling whether the default behavior should be prevented or not: https://jsfiddle.net/mpo40jxa/ You can see that when it's not prevented, text/html renders as red and plain-text is just the textContent (Selection.toString()).  If you wanted to have the **markup** copied as plain-text, then do not set the `text/html` data.